# Rename 'transfer' tag to 'data-transfer'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup, retag-request

To avoid confusion, I request we rename the [transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) (x13) to `data-transfer`.

**Explanation:** We already have the [file-transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer) (x96). I just went over the questions tagged `transfer`, and re-tagged a few which rather referred to `file-transfer`. To avoid people confusing these two tags, IMHO we should do the above mentioned tag-rename.

**Optional part:** for disambiguity, we could make `transfer` a synonym to one of the two. Some facts about background for the two tags to be considered in this case: While "file-transfer" clearly refers to "files", obviously, "data-transfer" is less clear a term. Taking a look at the questions tagged such, it refers to...

- PIM data such as contacts (x4, plus 1 mixed)
- messages: SMS/MMS (x4)
- app-data (x2)
- other data: links via bluetooth, WiFi APNs (x2)

So we could also think of creating a new [contact-transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contact-transfer) tag, which would make sense, and re-tag those 4+1 questions, optionally do the same for `message-transfer`, and then renaming "transfer" to "data-transfer".

Comment: I'd personally be okay with simply renaming the tag to `data-transfer` and explaining in the wiki that it's for moving *any* kind of data between devices (contacts, app data, messages, etc) except for flat files. Then we could let that cover anything that isn't a "file transfer".

Comment: Once you've done the rename, simply answer this Q and I will setup the tag wiki accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renamed the tag to [data-transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer) to handle anything other than file transfers. Still a broad-ish tag, but should hopefully not get confused with [file-transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer) (at least not as much) or other things.

Comment: Thanks! Tag-wiki created (just needs to be app-|im-proved :)